# Point a typedef function to another function in another class

Tags: c++, typedef

I have this typedef function on Class A.h:

```
typedef void(*PERCENTAGE_CALLBACK)(float);
```

And I am using on one of the class' function:

```
int API_GenerateLayerData(int layerIndex, unsigned char *data, int dataSize, PERCENTAGE_CALLBACK callback);
```

In Another Class (ClassB.cpp), I have this function that returns nothing(void) but accepts a float value just like **PERCENTAGE_CALLBACK**:

```
void ClassB::Update(float progress)
{
    emit ChangeProgress((int)progress);
}
```

But when I initialize the PERCENTAGE_CALLBACK object to be used and passed on the function in the ClassA it throws an error:

```
public void someFunction()
{
    ClassA *a = new ClassA();

    PERCENTAGE_CALLBACK callback = &ClassB::Update; //Error: cannot convert void ti PERCENTAGE_CALLBACK

    a->API_GenerateLayerData(someNum, someData, count, callback);
}
```

> How do I initialize the Class A's callback that points to the Class B's Update Function?

Comment: Like @Klaus already said: You are mixing function pointer and pointer to member function. Here is great C++ FAQ about [Pointers to Member Functions](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members#fnptr-vs-memfnptr-types)

Comment: I'm sorry, I just migrated from c# to c++ @Xplatforms

Comment: you don't need to be sorry about that :) Read the FAQ about member pointers, it has examples too

Comment: Are you free to change the signature of `API_GenerateLayerData`?

Comment: I can but it is only a wrapper for an externall DLL that uses the same parameters. @acraig5075

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply can't do that because calling a member function also needs a object on which the member should be called.

If your api only provide a function pointer, independent of which signature it is, you can't work around this problem even not by `std::bind` nor by using lambda functions. Both of them are also "callable" objects and as this, they also need a object pointer or reference for the callback.

If you are able to change your API you are using, you should change the callback registration to `std::function`. `std::function` is able to handle plain function pointers and also lambdas or any other combination of object/method combination.

Comment: @TerribleDog: Please read again my answer! You can't! You have change the interface of your callback registration to accept also member function pointer and object. This can be simplified by using `std::function` as parameter. Your current interface is not able to handle member callbacks. As this, there is no way to initialize something to a value which can not be used!

Comment: It's from a DLL so I'm a bit confused. And also because I'm new to developing on c++. We're migrating our project from c#

Comment: @TerribleDog: If the API defined by your DLL did not allow to use member/object, you simply can't use them. Sounds that this is an old C-style API. If so, you can't use objects here. If you only have to register a single object with a member function, you can write a wrapper with a simple function which calls your object member. If you need to register multiple objects, you have to write your own callback registration in the wrapper code.

Comment: I created a wrapper that is a exact look-alike of the functions in the DLL. But it throws an exception whenever I use a callback object in the function being sent to the DLL. I'm really sorry if I can't fully comprehend what you're trying to imply.

Comment: @TerribleDog: Seems to be the next problem. So please write another question and present your code and error messages. We should not discuss a long down all your coding problems on a single question here...